# How do you check the windows version in Win32 at runtime?

Tags: winapi

How do you check the windows version in Win32 at runtime?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the [`GetVersionEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451(VS.85).aspx) or [`VerifyVersionInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725492(VS.85).aspx) functions.

Comment: And when using GetVersion[Ex], remember to check version numbers with the future in mind. For example, to check for XP and higher: major > 5 OR (major==5 and minor >= 1)

Answer (score 2):

GetVersionEx has been deprecated. We will need to use [Version Helper functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: The version helper functions are just wrappers for `VerifyVersionInfo()`. Note that `GetVersion/Ex()` on Windows 8.1+, and `VerifyVersionInfo()` on Windows 10+, are subject to manifestation and thus **lie to apps** that are not manifested to declare explicit compatibility with the Windows version being run on. To get the *true* Windows version without manifestation, you need to use `RtlGetVersion()`, `NetServerGetInfo()`, or `NetWkstaGetInfo()` instead.