# How do i get "winver"?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to get the version number presented in cmd command "winver", which in my case is 20H2. How do i get that with code? I have found no posts covering this topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you check the windows version in Win32 at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457872/how-do-you-check-the-windows-version-in-win32-at-runtime)

Comment: I don't think that duplicate would print `20H2`

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you maintain a map of build numbers and their strings, like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int,std::string> builds = {{19042, "20H2"}, {19043, "21H1"}};
    std::cout << builds.at(19042) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and you would get the build number with [`GetVersion()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversion) or `GetVersionEx()`. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Channels) for a list. Note that the build number may be subject to compatibility settings, i.e. Windows may be lying to you.

IMHO Microsoft recommended to check the version of a system DLL like `kernel32.dll` with [`GetFileVersionInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfoa) to get the real version.

If you don't like any of these, getting the name from the Registry may be the option you're looking for:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DisplayVersion
```

Comment: Hmm, strange. While `winver` says 21H1, the kernel32.dll and ntdll.dll are 19041 on my machine. I'm a little bit worried now.

Comment: 21H1 is a marketing name. dll files use normal build numbers like they always have.

Comment: @Anders: I know, but 21H1 should be 19043, not 19041