# Windows: Determine OS version in C from Cygwin

Tags: windows, winapi, operating-system, cygwin

I've got some code that's running in the Cygwin environment, which makes Windows look like Unix.
I want to get the OS version but the Posix function call uname doesn't exist.
Is there another way to get it programmatically?
I'm using the GCC compiler;
I don't have any Microsoft development software installed.

Comment: Cygwin has a package for the Windows API header files, so you can `#include <windows.h>` and then call any of the functions mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457872/how-do-you-check-the-windows-version-in-win32-at-runtime   Yes, even with gcc.

Comment: Is there any #ifdef I could use to check whether that package is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct utsname utsname;
    if (uname(&utsname) == 0) {
        printf("sysname = %s\n", utsname.sysname);
        printf("nodename = %s\n", utsname.nodename);
        printf("release = %s\n", utsname.release);
        printf("version = %s\n", utsname.version);
    #if __GNU_VISIBLE
        printf("domainname = %s\n", utsname.domainname);
    #else
        printf("domainname = %s\n", utsname.__domainname);
    #endif
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
sysname = CYGWIN_NT-10.0-22621
nodename = hostname
release = 3.4.5-1.x86_64
version = 2023-01-19 19:09 UTC
domainname =
```

Comment: *"Try this"*-type answers are virtually useless. The bare minimum an answer needs to provide is identifying the issue and acknowledging how the proposed solution addresses the issue.

Comment: That's what I tried but the header sys/utsname.h was missing.

Comment: @s_question In Cygwin, the header file sys/utsname.h is part of the cygwin package itself. The cygwin package provides the base Cygwin library that offers the POSIX API functionality. Can you run the command : `find /usr/include -name utsname.h`

Comment: @Philippe Yes that's what I did. It was missing. Maybe someone can alert the maintainers? I selected to download from vt.edu as usual, as I've done for years.

Comment: Have you tried to install cygwin in a fresh directory and see if `sys/utsname.h` exists ?